# MS Report Builder Subreport returning same record for each separate record on main report

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have researched this topic, but the responses have not seemed to help.  I set up a report in Microsoft SQL Report Builder (I am doing this with widgets, not code).  I then set up a sub-report.

The sub-report has a parameter and a filter which refers to the parameter.

The main report has a parameter as well which refers to the identifier that ties the two reports (employee id).

I have used the sub-report properties after embedding the sub-report to set a parameter of the two parameters (main and sub) matching.

What I am getting in the main report is a correct main report, but the sub-report repeats the first person (on the main report)'s information on each separate page of the report.  (The report is grouped by employee id and I have a page break after each group.)